# Question on Correspondences

Tags: real-analysis

$$\varphi(\theta) =   \begin{cases} {0} &  \text{for } & \theta=0 \\
{\sin \left({1\over \theta}\right)} & \text{for  }& \theta \neq0 \end{cases}$$

$\varphi$ is  a correspondence from $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$. Show whether this correspondence is upper hemicontinuous or/and lowerhemicontinuous.

Comment: What is a correspondence?

Comment: @Rasmus Simply a function?

Comment: @Rasmus A correspondence is a set-valued function or multifunction. See http://books.google.nl/books?id=4hIq6ExH7NoC&lpg=PA569&dq=aliprantis%20correspondence&pg=PA556#v=onepage&q=aliprantis%20correspondence&f=false

Comment: Multi-Valued Functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\varphi$ is neither upper-- nor lower hemicontinuous.

If $\varphi$  were lower hemicontinuous, it would have a continuous selection by the Michael selection theorem, which is not the case.

It holds that $\varphi(0)=\{0\}\subseteq (-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2})$, while there exists no neighborhood $U$ of zero such that $z\in U$ implies $\varphi(z)\subseteq (-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2})$. So $\varphi$ is not upper hemicontinuous.

Comment: For single-valued correspondences, upper- and lower hemi-continuity are equivalent, so one side is enough. Using the Michael selection theorem here is using a plasma cannon to hunt for bugs.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker, yeah probably. But the bugs are dead right? ;)